# Play and record video while playing some background music

Tags: ios

I looked in several forums and they all couldn't deliver a satisfying answer.

My wish is to be able to play and record video while playing music at the background.
I managed to do that with the help of a snippet I found. here is the code:

```
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
session.delegate = self;

NSError *error = nil;
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];

OSStatus propertySetError = 0;

UInt32 allowMixing = true; 

propertySetError = AudioSessionSetProperty (

                                            kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,  // 1

                                            sizeof (allowMixing),                                 // 2

                                            &allowMixing                                          // 3

                                            );
[session setActive:YES error:&error];
```

The problem is while recording, I can only hear the background music through the ear speaker instead of the regular speaker.

How can I set the regular speaker to work so that the recording session won't be interrupted?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: hey do you have a sample code of what you did here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you override the seesion category with *kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers* it uses the smaller speaker on the top side of the device (besides the frontend camera). To use the regular speaker as the output device, you should instead redirect the output route of your audio session. The following is the code snippet of achieving this

```
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;

AudioSessionSetProperty ( 
    kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,                         
    sizeof (audioRouteOverride),                                      
    &audioRouteOverride                                               
);
```

Replace this code with your above and it will work. You can further refer [Redirect Output Audio](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW13) on apple developer portal.