# iOS - Play audio/sound while record a video

Tags: ios, audio, video, avaudioplayer

I need to play audio sound from the main speaker of the iPhone while the user is recording a video. Is it possible? How can i do?
I need the sound is being played from the main speaker so in that way I can record this sound in my video.

Comment: do you need to add sound to recorded video *or* do you specifically need to play sound while recording?

Comment: I need to add sound to the recorded video without modify the original audio. The problem is that if I add my sound after recorded the video I cannot manage the correct volume for my sound according to the one of the video @Kreiri

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463185/play-and-record-video-while-playing-some-backgorund-music)

He was already using video and sound the way you want, except the routing was wrong... An answer there has a code snipped that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by setting  `AVAudioSession` class property and using `AVAudioPlayer` to play sound

Set `AVAudioSession` category property to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` and also set its category options to `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers` this will solve the problem. Please check the below set of code

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"VoicemailSound" ofType:@"mp3"]]; //Download and add a system sound to your project and mention its name and type here
 self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error: nil];

 [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
 [self.audioPlayer play];
```