# Simultaneously recording video and playing audio file

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am developing an iPhone app in which there is requirement of recording a video from iPhone front camera and simultaneously playing an audio file in between. I used AVCamCaptureManager for recording video.
I am recording video using dispatch_queue in background as follow:

```
 // ------ This will start recording in Background --------

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    [self startRecordingInBackground];
});
```

It works fine until some audio file is played.

```
    // ----- Playing Audio File ---------
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Start_b4_counting_down" ofType:@"mp3" inDirectory:Nil];
    NSLog(@"filePath %@", filePath);
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: filePath];
    self.theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:NULL];
    self.theAudio.volume = 10.0;
    self.theAudio.delegate = self;
    [self.theAudio prepareToPlay];
    [self.theAudio play];
```

As soon as the audio file is played the video recording stops and does not resume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have an idea about this topic but maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463185/play-and-record-video-while-playing-some-backgorund-music) will be helpful for you.
Good luck!