# Record video while music playing (Snapchat)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm wondering if there's a way to code a function that allows PBJVision to record a video while user is playing their own music in the background.

Answer (score 1):

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions: [AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DuckOthers,AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker])
```

this worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

That is only possible if you're recording only video not video with audio.
I have created app, where I'm recording video only and on that user able to play it's music while recording video through my app.

Comment: Seems to be possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463185/play-and-record-video-while-playing-some-backgorund-music

Comment: Just don't know how to configure it for PBJVision

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's definitely possible.

I have followed the link: [Allows music playback during recording video like snapchat ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715597/allows-music-playback-during-recording-video-like-snapchat-ios)  and implemented the below code which is working quite nicely!!

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord  withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:nil];

[session setActive:YES error:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```